# Fetching results from inner query having comma separated values - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table having two columns - key and value:

**temp_tbl:**

```
key value
---|-----
k1 | a','b
```

Below is the insert script with which I am storing the value in temp_tbl:

```
insert into temp_tbl values ('k1', 'a'+char(39)+char(44)+char(39)+'b');
```

Now, I want trying to fetch records from another table (actual_tbl) like this:

```
select * from actual_tbl where field_value in 
(select value from tamp_tbl where key = 'k1');--query 1
```

But this is not returning anything.

I want the above query to behave like the following one:

```
select * from actual_tbl where field_value in 
('a','b');--query 2
```

Where am I doing wrong in query 1?

I am using **sql server**.

Comment: We don't store more than one value in a field. This is mistake number 1 and it's the root of the rest of your problems. Furthermore `a','b` is not the same as `'a','b'` so your insert is broken. Even if you fix it though, your schema is still going to cause you massive issues. Your `temp_tbl` should have two records in it: `k1, a`, and `k1, b`. Then your `SELECT` will work.

Comment: Even if I store `a','b` as `'a','b`' it is not working.

Comment: Right. Go read that first and last sentence. Here it is again: Don't store more than one value in a field. Instead: `INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ('k1', 'a'); INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES ('k1', 'b');` Anytime you think of storing delimited data in a single field, think again. It's not how an RDBMS works and it will only cause pain.

Comment: What is up with the single quotes only on one side of the values?  This doesn't make sense to me.  Did you intend to include the quotes on both sides (or maybe neither side) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Where am I doing wrong in query 1?

Where you are going wrong is in failing to understand the way the IN keyword works with a subquery vs a hard-coded list.

When an IN clause is followed by a list, each item in the list is a discrete value:

```
IN ('I am a value', 'I am another value', 'I am yet another value')
```

When it's followed by a sub-query, each row generates a single value.   Your temp table only has one row, so the IN clause is only considering a single value.   No matter how you try to "trick" the parser with commas and single-quotes, **it won't work**.  The SQL Server parser is too smart to be tricked.   It will know that a single value of `'a','b'` is still just a single value, and it will look for that single value.  It won't treat them as two separate values like you are trying to do.